# Two-column Bibliography with bibitem in the first column

Tags: bibliographies, two-column

I am trying to make my bibliography have two columns with each \bibitem appearing in the first one (a regular two-column table). This is an example of what the desired output looks like:

[image]

For a reason, I am using `thebibliography` to generate biblio manually. My code looks e.g. like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{13}
\footnotesize
...
\bibitem[Blog]{bib.blog} \emph{CloverETL's Blog on Data Integration:
CloverETL tips and advice from data integration experts} [online]. 2012 [quoted 2012-03-14]. Available  at: \url{http://blog.cloveretl.com/}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

I have been experimenting with `minipage`, `multicols(*)`, tables (TeX will not let me separate `\bibitem` from the rest of the entries by `&`) with no success.

Answer (score 4):

Redefine the `thebibliography` environment and the `\@biblabel` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \footnotesize
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\bfseries[#1]}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\smash{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedright\bfseries[#1]}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{Axaptapedia, Sure Step}

\bibitem[Blog]{bib.blog} \emph{CloverETL's Blog on Data Integration: CloverETL tips and advice from data integration 
experts} [online]. 2012 [quoted 2012-03-14]. Available at: \url{http://blog.cloveretl.com/}

\bibitem[Axaptapedia, Sure Step Methodology]{axa} \emph{CloverETL's Blog on Data Integration: CloverETL tips and 
advice from data integration experts} [online]. 2012 [quoted 2012-03-14]. Available at: 
\url{http://blog.cloveretl.com/}

\end{thebibliography} 

\end{document}
```

The argument to the environment will tell LaTeX how big you want the labels to appear.

[image]

Comment: That was some speed. Excellent, it works!! Thanks a ton. Furthermore, I tweaked your snippet by setting:

    `\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
    \renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}`

EDIT (off-topic, I admit): Could we make those brackets round () instead of square []? So that they would appear like that both in Bibliography and in-document quotations when I use `\cite{}`. I know this is a kind of tough to achieve when not using `natbib`.

Comment: @user1059971 The brackets are, as you can see, in the definition of `\@biblabel`; just change them into parentheses.

Comment: You are right, this did help me with () in Bibliography. However, because I use custom labels as in `\bibitem[Blog]{bib.blog}`, what I get when citing is always like [Blog]. I have been trying to figure out how to change it to (Blog). `\parencite` does exactly what I want, but I cannot use it beacuse `biblatex` is not compatible with my source. Any clues?

Comment: @user1059971 Add `\renewcommand{\@cite}[2]{({#1\if@tempswa, #2\fi})}` before `\makeatother`

Comment: Smooth!! That is exactly what my dissertation needed :-). Thank you very much. This is such a splendid website, saving me a lot of effort. Looks like I will be popping in more often.

Comment: @user1059971 You're welcome. Consider changing your nickname. :)